# Changing radius/degree to x,y coordinate for output of a value at a point

Tags: python-3.x, color-picker

I'm working on my final project for class, which is a program that displays the HSV values for a color and then allows the user to click on the color to display it and then choose a lightness value for it. There is a lot of code that I don't want to post here, so I've made a few pastebin posts and linked them here.

My friend/classmate made a circular color wheel, and I am trying to adapt his color selection method into a rectangular color spectrum so we can have both to display for the professor and write about the pros/cons, etc. of each.

My color displays correctly, but I am having trouble getting the color selection to work, and I have a sneaking suspicion that it has to do with this part:

```
def color_from_point(x, y, l):
    degree = abs(degrees(atan(y / x)))
    c = abs(x / cos(radians(degree)))
    if x < 0 and y >= 0:
        degree = (90 - degree) + 90
    elif x < 0 and y < 0:
        degree = degree + 180
    elif x >= 0 and y <= 0:
        degree = (90 - degree) + 270

    if c > 255:
        color = "White"
    else:
        color = colors(c / 255, degree, (l / 100))

    return color
```

I am a complete beginner coder, and I'm not sure what to do to change this from using radius and degrees to using just the x,y coordinate to give me the color.

Here is the link to the pastebin post of the circular color picker of a friend/classmate:

http://pastebin.com/gAEg6rA1

Link to my WIP rectangular version:

http://pastebin.com/MJcqvvJw

Thanks in advance for any and all help!!

Comment: Why would you use `atan()` instead of `atan2()`?

Comment: Not sure...this is the code from my friend/classmate that he used to get the color value from a point on his circular color wheel.  I'm trying to figure out what I need to do so I can change it to using the X,Y coordinates to give me the color on my rectangular display.